# How can I get the total number of calls to my dynamodb table?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm working with AWS Lambda. I created a lambda function that perform a get operation to my dynamoDB table. Depending on the id (primary key) I pass to this get function, it should return me the correct item in JSON format. For that, I'm using the get_item function from boto3:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.get_item

So normally, if a call my lambda function via an API (created from API Gateway) by specifying and ID, I should get the corresponding item. The problem is that I also need to get the number of times I retrieved a result. For example, if it's the seventh time I call my lambda function, I should get an item (still depending on the id) and the index 7, like this :

```
{
  "7":{
        "id" :1246 ,
        "toy":"car",
        "color": "red"
      }
}
```

Logically, the number of times that I call my lambda function is the number of times that I call dynamoDB. Than I suppose that the correct way to get this number is by maybe using dynamodb, but I already spent hours trying to find a way to get this number of events/calls to my table by looking everywhere... What can I do to get this number ? and how could I implement this using boto3?

Answer (score 2):

There is no out of box solution to get the number of calls to the table in DynamoDb. You need to write a custom counter that will be shared across Lambda calls.

The easiest option and the fastest solution is probably using Redis and it's `INCR` operation to perform atomic increments. If you're not familiar with Redis, check the [doc for INCR operation](https://redis.io/commands/incr) and specifically the `Pattern: Counter` section.

If you only can use the DynamoDb, you need to maintain a counter in a separate single item. Example:

```
{
  "partionKey": "counter_item",
  "counter": 1
}
```

Then you can execute update calls to increment the counter like that:

```
response = table.update_item(
        Key={'partionKey': {'S': ':pk'}},
        TableName='your_table_name',
        ReturnValues='ALL_NEW',
        UpdateExpression='SET #counter = if_not_exists(#counter, :default) + :incr',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
          ':pk': 'counter_item',
          ':incr': 1,
          ':default': 0
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
          '#counter': 'counter'
        }
        )
```

There will be an updated item in the response so you can get the `counter` field from it.
You can check [this DynamoDb guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.04) for better examples in python.

Comment: " you need to maintain a counter in a separate single item. " What do you mean by that ? Do you store this in a new table ?

Comment: In general, it's recommended to put different types of data into a single table in the NoSQL design. So both types of entities will be stored in the same table but have different partition keys that never overlap. 
Single-table design has a lot of benefits but some drawbacks as well and you might need to put some effort to dig into the topic. I can recommend [DDB Design Best Practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html) article for starters and [this talk by Rick Houlihan](https://youtu.be/HaEPXoXVf2k) for deep dive into NoSQL design

Comment: However, if the topic sounds too complicated for your case, it's completely OK to put this counter into a new table. You'll lose some scaling possibilities, but you probably don't need to scale that much

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are plenty of ways to find out the number of server calls.

> 1. If you have the logs you can easily get the server calls of any of the specific pages.
> 2. Use the AWS Dashboard to get the info matrices. (It has everything, latency, failure ratio, calls, etc.)
> 3. Write your own function which can count the get, post, and update calls. (It will be similar to profile hits, generally, this is used at
>    the initial stage of a project.)